# Radius Search From Database

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a database of addresses for Accounts in Australia.
I need to build a solution whereby the user can select a postcode or suburb and Google Maps queries the database to find accounts within a radius of 50kms from the postcode / suburb and displays markers on the map for each account that falls within these boundries.
Can somebody please help me with this?

Thanks,

Comment: I'd suggest finding a database that converts postal codes to map coordinates. When you have those two datasets linked, it's a simple matter of between coordx min - coordx max and coordy min - coordy max.

Answer (score 0):

See [the articles section of the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/), there is an [article how to build a store locator](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3) which should be applicable (the concepts if not the code).