# Is it possible to search within KML layers with Google Place Search API?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, kml, google-places-api

I have a Javascript which consists of map API. Meanwhile I have KML map layer which I created with Google Map Engine (Lite) and I have integrated that KML layer into my map as follows,

```
function initialize() {

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(6.990440,81.055313);
var mapOptions = {
  center: pyrmont,
  zoom: 11,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
    mapOptions);

var ctaLayer = new google.maps.KmlLayer({
    url: 'http://mapsengine.google.com/map/u/0/kml?mid=z77FHFP6y-14......'
});
ctaLayer.setMap(map);

var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: '2500',
    keyword: 'school'
  };

service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
service.radarSearch(request, callback);
```

I have added some points into that KML layer but, when I perform a radarSearch on my map it does not recognize those points within my KML layer…

Please Help…

Comment: Google Places API will not return results from your KML.  If you want those (or want those in addition to the ones from the Places API), you  need to implement that search yourself.

Comment: @geocodezip any idea how?

Comment: That question is way to broad.  There are lots of ways to do it.

Comment: I have a KML generated from a db locally can i feed that into places and query that at the same time?

Comment: If you have the data in a database, query the database (it would be better if it geographically enabled, but it doesn't have to be) for locations within your desired radius. See [this possible duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11624593/radius-search-from-database)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it's not specifically, possible to use Google Place Search API to search a KML file, but you can use plain old javascript to do a search within a KML file. The steps you would need to do are to

- Load the KML file in a form that your script can read (perhaps JSON)
- traverse the KML data and filter the data you want
- show the result of the search

So a simple implementation would be to Use yahoo pipes to convert the KML file to JSON and load it with `$.ajax`. Deals with Same-Origin policy and also parsing the KML. We then store the relevant data for searching later

```
var searchData=null
$.ajax("http://pipes.yahoo.com/pipes/pipe.run?_id=10a81555228e77349570df1cc6823ed2&_render=json&urlinput1=" + kmlURL)
 .done(function (data) {
    searchData=data.value.items[0].Document.Placemark //structure of yahoo pipe
})
```

Create a simple search function. Here we just do a really rough text search as a proof of concept and we can add radius search by using Google map's calculations as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16111124/calculate-distance-between-current-location-and-and-a-different-location-using-g)

```
function searchKML(request,callback){
    var ret=[]
    if(!searchData) return
    for(var i=0;i<searchData.length;i++){
        //insert distance search. continue if too far
        if( searchData[i].description.indexOf(request.keyword)!=-1 ||   
            searchData[i].name.indexOf(request.keyword)!=-1 ){
            ret.push(searchData[i])
        }
    }
    callback(ret)
}
```

A function to create a marker for the resulting search

```
function createMarkerKML(place){
    var loc=place.Point.coordinates.split(",")
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(loc[1],loc[0])
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
        infowindow.setContent(place.name);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
    })
}
```

With those in place, you can integrate a search with Google's own search by just calling `searchKML` with the regular search

```
function searchMap(str) {
    var request = {
        location: map.getCenter(),
        radius: '2500',
        keyword: str
    };
    service.radarSearch(request, callback); //normal search
    searchKML(request,function(results){
        for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
            createMarkerKML(results[i]);
        }
    })

}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mfirdaus/4W3t8/)